# PERC 5/i Enable alarm on disks failures

Tags: raid, configuration, dell

I'm trying to enable one the alarm of my server's raid controller PERC 5/i.

[Using this documentation](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/PERC5/en/UG/HTML/chapterj.htm), under the chapter `Audible Alarm Warnings`, it's explained that enabling an audible alarm is allowed in order to quickly spot failures on my hard disks.

My trouble is that when entering the disk controller configuration (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot time), I'm able to set up lot of things but I cannot navigate to `Enable Audible Alarm`. I have :

- `Enable Controller BIOS`
- `Enable Alarm`
- `Enable BIOS stop on Error`

I can navigate with my arrow keys to both the first and third items, but I cannot navigate to or select the second! It's not greyed out, and seems like I should be able to select go on this entry, but my cursor keep skipping it.

Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  You're missing the fact that the [PERC5/i cards (the internal variants) do not have an audible alarm](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/p/18382417/18505403.aspx#18505403). The PERC5/e cards (the "external" variants) do.

You should probably set up a more reliable alarm mechanism like email or SMS notifications anyway, honestly.

**EDIT**:

For a more official source of this information, see the [Dell support e-document here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/6.3/en/OMSS/apndx.htm#wp1081809).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yeah, I know that would definitely the best way to go but our server is driving a automation machine that is not (at least for now) connected to any network. We'll have to correct this sooner than expected :)